# Schengen Visa for Italy

Tags: schengen-visas, europe, italy, visa-shopping

I am planning a trip to Italy from 2nd May to 11th May from Dublin. I have booked my flights and hotels and I have all Schengen visa related documents ready with me.

However, when I tried to check the appointment I found there is no slot available before 7th May.

Could anyone please suggest me what is the best thing to do now?

Is there a way to get visa from Italy embassy in urgent basis? or

Can I get Schengen visa for a different country and first travel to that country, spent a day or two there and then enter Italy?

For visa purpose I can show I am staying more days in that country than Italy. Can there be a problem with border control in Italy?

Please help me, I don't want to drop my entire plan :(

Regards,

Sitabja

Answer (score 1):

If your main destination is Italy, you must apply for a visa from Italy. If you apply to a different country for a visa for a trip where Italy is clearly the main destination, they will probably refuse your visa saying you have to apply to Italy and not even look at the rest of the application.

You must not misrepresent your itinerary to get a visa (we nickname that 'visa shopping' if it gets you a different consulate). Being caught out can mean your entry is refused and you get a black mark on your record.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to get appointment to Italy Embassy in urgent basis?